# Como gerar pares de valores aleatórios

Tags: c, random

Queria gerar 6 valores aleatórios em 2 duplas por exemplo 1 1, 2 2, 3 3, porém não estou obtendo sucesso meu código

Meu código

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int vezes(int vetor[], int tamanho, int numero);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int vetor[6], num, resu;
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
     num = rand() % 8;
     if(i != 0)
     {
        resu = vezes(vetor, i, num);
        while(resu)
        {
            num = rand() % 8;
            resu = vezes(vetor, i, num);
        }
     }
     vetor[i] = num;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
     printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
  }
   return 0;
}

int vezes(int vetor[], int tamanho, int numero)
{
  int cont = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
  {
     if(vetor[i] == numero)
     {
        cont++;
     }
 }
  if(cont <= 2)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer. Você quer 3 números aleatórios e que ele apareça repetido, é isso? E vai até quanto até um?

Comment: maneiro ai foi só um exemplo, o numero de valores tem que variar até de 0 até 7

Comment: mas você tem que esclarecer melhor caso contrário não tem como ajudar.

Comment: vou dá um exemplo melhor 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 ,3, no caso existem dois 1, dois 2, dois 3, deu para você entender

Comment: Então é o que eu falei, você quer 3 números possivelmente diferentes que podem ir de 0 a 7, e aí cada um deles devem aparecer obrigatoriamente de novo? É isso? Pode ser 1 2 1 1 2 1?

Comment: na verdade está quase certo, cada numero só pode repetir 2 vezes

Comment: Sabe o que é aleatório? É um belo dia você [acordar Michael Stevens](https://youtu.be/sMb00lz-IfE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se foi pra você que eu falei, precisa entender o que está fazendo, já está fazendo várias perguntas aqui e mostra que não entende nada do que está acontecendo no código, não está aprendendo assim. Seus código continuam mal escritos, que é algo que nem exige muito conhecimento. Continua errando em coisas que já foram ensinadas. Nem estou falando de lógica.

Um problemas é não entender claramente qual é o problema e comunicar qual é ele. É um problema anterior à programação. precisa trabalhar isso para conseguir programar.

A lógica está confusa demais, e é porque não entende o problema. É muito mais simples. Inclusive a performance é melhor. E provavelmente dá para melhorar mais.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void shuffle(int *array, int tamanho) { //sorteia garantidamente único - algoritmo Fisher-Yates
    for (int i = tamanho - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int j = rand() % (i + 1);
        int tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int roll[8] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }; //cria os valore permitidos
    shuffle(roll, 8); //embaralha
    int resultado[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //só escolhe 3 números conforme a definição
        resultado[i] = roll[i];
        resultado[i + 3] = roll[i]; //repete o número
    }
    shuffle(resultado, 6); //embaralha os números que estavam agrupados
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) printf("%d ", resultado[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5EETmy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cxuvdtzx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/RandomUniqueRepetead.c).